# Wordpress-Illegal string offset 'panels_info'

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a solution on how to proceed in fixing this Wordpress error:Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array 
code sample line 586:
    $widget['panels_info']['widget_index'] = $i;

Comment: Well, what's on line 586 of renderer.php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I added the code

Comment: I still don't know what line 586 says. Have you done any debugging on this at all?

Comment: I couldn`t find a sub-file named rendered in my WP contents folders as in  '/inc/renderer' in the warning message I got